# Could not find the bundle com/ibm/icu/impl/data/icudt65b/ru_RU/

Tags: javafx, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I am using gluonfx-maven-plugin 1.0.19 with graalvm-ce-java17-22.3.3 for windows 11. This can be checked from the log below.

```
>mvn clean gluonfx:build

    [1/7] Initializing...
    Version info: 'GraalVM 22.3.3 Java 17 CE
    Java version info: '17.0.8+7-jvmci-22.3-b22
    C compiler: cl.exe (microsoft, x64, 19.29.30151)
    Garbage collector: Serial GC
    1 user-specific feature(s)
```

There is also an unpleasant line in the log

**The bundle named: com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt65b.ru, has not been found. If the bundle is part of a module, verify the bundle name is a fully qualified class name. Otherwise verify the bundle path is accessible in the classpath.**

The exucateble * .exe file is built. I run it and get exception
**Could not find the bundle com/ibm/icu/impl/data/icudt65b/ru_RU/**
Library de.gsi.chart.chartfx-chart throws it.

The library de.gsi.chart.chartfx-chart tries to read the file ru_RU. The library is present in class path and containts file ru_RU.
[image: See the screenshot]

I added bundlesList to [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/0JPmEaRG). Also you can see [module-info.java](https://pastebin.com/deCb14EJ)

**Problem 1**
Gluonfx plagin can not read bundle *com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt65b.ru* , not *com.ibm.icu.impl.data.icudt65b.ru_RU*.

**Problem 2**
Let's try read bundle `com/ibm/icu/impl/data/icudt65b/ru.res. Add a bundle

```
<bundlesList>
 <list>com/ibm/icu/impl/data/icudt65b/ru.res</list>
</bundlesList>
```

or creat the file *src/main/resources/META-INF/substrate/config/resourcebundles*

```
com/ibm/icu/impl/data/icudt65b/ru.res
Plugin read bundle name correctly but does not find it.
```

**The bundle named: com/ibm/icu/impl/data/icudt65b/ru.res, has not been found. If the bundle is part of a module, verify the bundle name is a fully qualified class name. Otherwise verify the bundle path is accessible in the classpath.**

Please help me.
Peace for everyone!

Comment: Have you tried `mvn gluonfx:runagent` before doing the build? That should find the used resources and add them properly to the native image.

Comment: Hmm... I'm doing `mvn gluonfx:runagent`. My program starts correctly and works correctly, then I click on the close button (the cross in the upper right corner), the program closes, but the maven process hangs (the console is locked). I have not overridden the handler of the close command in my code.

Comment: But did it generate the config files under `src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image`?

Comment: José Pered, ¡Gracias!  Everything worked, below I left a detailed comment

Comment: @JoséPereda Сan you tell me one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76847580/gluonhq-with-hibernate-could-not-resolve-net-bytebuddy-utility-invokerdispatch) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

José Pereda, ¡Gracias!

I added code

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(handler -> {
  Platform.exit();
  System.exit(0);
});
```

Then

```
mvn gluonfx:runagent
```

My app started correctly, I clicked the close button  (the cross in the upper right corner), it closed and agent process finished.
Then I did

```
mvn gluonfx:build
```

The app is built and started correctly!