# Gluonhq with Hibernate: Could not resolve net.bytebuddy.utility.Invoker$Dispatcher for reflection configuration

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I use gluon with hibernate. In the beginning I do

```
mvn gluonfx:runagent
```

The application launches, makes a request to the database and the data is displayed correctly.
[Here is the command log](https://pastebin.com/udkgKHnq)

Then I do

```
mvn clean gluonfx:build
```

The executable exe file is built, but does not run.
[Here is the command log](https://pastebin.com/zjbs1BVJ)

The problem is here:
**06 19:54:15 MSK 2023][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Could not resolve net.bytebuddy.utility.Invoker$Dispatcher for reflection configuration. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.utility.Invoker$Dispatcher.**

The dependency **net.bytebody.byte-buddy** was transitively derived from **hibernate-core**. And it scope is *runtime*. [See the screenshot](https://ibb.co/R2jsTb0)

I tried to exclude it from the hibernate-core and add it with a new scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.18</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
             <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
             <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The pom file is [here](https://pastebin.com/ja5PRgMV)

Nothing has changed, the same mistake.

Please tell me how to fix this problem!

Comment: You might need to follow this: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/1424 (which will require `<nativeImageArgs/>` in your pom).

Comment: @JoséPereda can you please take a look at my new question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916480/gluonhq-with-jdbc-sqlite-classnotfoundexception-org-graalvm-nativeimage-hoste