# Gluonhq with JDBC SQLite : ClassNotFoundException: org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.RuntimeRe

Tags: javafx, graalvm, gluon, graalvm-native-image, gluonfx

I am using Gluonhq with JDBC in Linux.

**Version info: 'GraalVM 22.1.0.1 Java 17 CE'**

There are no problems with postgresql. The problems begin when I work with sqlite.

My JDBC connect:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:sqlite:/home/alex/IdeaProjects/db/base/materials.db"
);
```

I do

```
mvn clean gluonfx:runagent
```

Everything works correctly, the data from sqlite database is read.

Then I do

```
mvn clean gluonfx:build
```

I got

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/graalvm/nativeimage/hosted/RuntimeResourceAccess
org.sqlite.nativeimage.SqliteJdbcFeature.handleLibraryResources(SqliteJdbcFeature.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.RuntimeResourceAccess**

[Here you can view the entire maven log](https://pastebin.com/uDy7ZrKm)

I added

```
<nativeImageArgs>
<arg>-Dorg.sqlite.lib.exportPath=/home/alex/IdeaProjects/</arg>
</nativeImageArgs>
```

And got new error

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/graalvm/nativeimage/hosted/RuntimeJNIAccess
org.sqlite.nativeimage.SqliteJdbcFeature.registerJNICalls(SqliteJdbcFeature.java:70
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.RuntimeJNIAccess**

**Row 70 of SqliteJdbcFeature.java:**  RuntimeJNIAccess.register(NativeDB.class);

I checked jni-config.json

```
{
  "name":"org.sqlite.core.DB",
  "methods":[
    {"name":"onCommit","parameterTypes":["boolean"] }, 
    {"name":"onUpdate","parameterTypes":["int","java.lang.String","java.lang.String","long"] }, 
    {"name":"throwex","parameterTypes":[] }, 
    {"name":"throwex","parameterTypes":["int"] }
  ]
},
{
  "name":"org.sqlite.core.DB$ProgressObserver",
  "methods":[{"name":"progress","parameterTypes":["int","int"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.sqlite.core.NativeDB",
  "fields":[
    {"name":"busyHandler"}, 
    {"name":"commitListener"}, 
    {"name":"pointer"}, 
    {"name":"progressHandler"}, 
    {"name":"updateListener"}
  ],
  "methods":[
    {"name":"stringToUtf8ByteArray","parameterTypes":["java.lang.String"] }, 
    {"name":"throwex","parameterTypes":["java.lang.String"] }
  ]
}, ...
```

[Here my pom](https://pastebin.com/4yK5wfBP)

Help!!

Comment: did you update your jsons with ```mvn gluonfx:runagent``` ?

Comment: @ozkanpakdil yes

Comment: I tried to build with your pom but got ```[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project povadka: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.alextim.povadka:povadka:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.alextim:alfaBetaDetectorServer:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
``` can you share your project or put a small reproducer ? @Martin

Comment: there's nothing interesting there. Just remove this dependency from the POM file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recolved my problem by replacing dependecy

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.42.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

witch

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.willena</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.35.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed Sqlite-Jdbc updated from 3.42.0.0 to 3.44.0.0

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.44.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please always use the preview window before posting here - I have formatted this code for you.